# How to return only the final fetch call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am building a react application that gives you information on stocks when you input their name. The problem is that when I type in info the data the information for that stock comes up but the remaining pending fetch calls override the original data and it reverts back to zero because that symbol doesn't exist. I have tried async and await but that is not doing the trick. I have also tried to set a timeout function on the call but that doesn't work either. Is their any way to get the final fetch call and ignore the other pending data?

[image]

```
 componentDidMount() {

        const { userInput, symbol1 } = this.state
        const urls = [
            `https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/ref-data/symbols`
        ]

        let requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url))
        Promise.all(requests)
            .then(responses => {
                return Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.json()));
            }).then(responses => {
                this.setState({
                    stockSymbol: responses[0]
                })
            })
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapShot) {
        const { userInput, symbol1 } = this.state;

        if (prevState.userInput !== userInput) {
            fetch(`https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote?symbol=${userInput}&token=budo2rv48v6spq9og4p0`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(responses => console.log(responses))
        }


    }
```

Comment: You need to do what's called debouncing. It will fire the function only once, after a specific timeout. So that if they keep typing, it won't execute until they stop typing after X milliseconds. There's plenty of vanilla JS examples of it, or you can use a library  like lodash for it

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an `AbortController` instance and use it to cancel previous requests when a new one is initiated.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function YourComponent() {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('');
  const [stockSymbol, setStockSymbol] = useState(null);
  const abortControllerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Your code for fetching stock symbols in the initial render
  }, []); // Empty dependency array for componentDidMount

  useEffect(() => {
    if (abortControllerRef.current) {
      // Cancel the previous request if it exists
      abortControllerRef.current.abort();
    }

    // Create a new AbortController
    const abortController = new AbortController();
    abortControllerRef.current = abortController;

    fetch(`https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote?symbol=${userInput}&token=budo2rv48v6spq9og4p0`, {
      signal: abortController.signal, // Associate the signal with this fetch request
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((responses) => {
        console.log(responses);
        setStockSymbol(responses);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.name === 'AbortError') {
          console.log('Previous fetch request was aborted.');
        } else {
          console.error('Error during fetch:', error);
        }
      });

    return () => {
      // Cleanup by aborting any pending requests when the component unmounts
      abortController.abort();
    };
  }, [userInput]);

  return (
    // Your component rendering code
  );
}

export default YourComponent;
```

1. The component initializes two state variables: `userInput` and `stockSymbol`, using the `useState` hook.
2. It also creates a `ref` called `abortControllerRef` using the `useRef` hook. This ref will hold the instance of the `AbortController`.
3. The first `useEffect` hook is used for fetching stock symbols during the initial render. It is triggered only once, as it has an empty dependency array (`[]`), simulating the behavior of `componentDidMount`.
4. The second `useEffect` hook is responsible for fetching stock data based on the `userInput`. It is triggered whenever `userInput` changes.

   - It first checks if there is a previous fetch request and cancels it by calling `abort()` on the `abortController` instance stored in the `abortControllerRef`.
   - Then, it creates a new `AbortController` and associates its signal with the fetch request using the `signal` property.
   - The fetch request is made to the API, passing the `userInput` and `API token` in the URL.
   - The response is converted to `JSON` and logged to the console. The stock data is also set in the `stockSymbol` state variable using `setStockSymbol`.
   - Any errors during the fetch request are caught, and if the error name is `AbortError`, it means that the previous fetch request was aborted. Otherwise, the error is logged to the console.
   - Finally, a cleanup function is returned from the `useEffect` hook. This function is called when the component unmounts or when the `userInput` changes. It aborts any pending requests by calling `abort()` on the `abortController`.

This should help....